# How to calculate LAI (Leaf Area Index) using Remote Sensing?

Tags: remote-sensing, lai

I am new in remote sensing, and I would like to ask the community what are some good methods to calculate the Leaf Area Index (LAI) using Remote Sensing Data, for agriculture mostly applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The methods to calculate LAI vary greatly with the data you want to use. Calculation by combining multispectral data and in-situ measurements use different methods than ones based on high-res LiDAR data or hyperspectral images.

I'd suggest you start out by reading a review about the topic, such as:

Zheng& Moskal (2009): *Retrieving Leaf Area Index (LAI) Using Remote Sensing: Theories, Methods and Sensors*. Sensors. doi:10.3390/s90402719.

This article is [Open Access](http://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/9/4/2719) and accessible by anyone.

Then you need to either select a method and start collecting the necessary data or you already have data and select a method that works with your dataset.

Answer (score 3):

While it is not my area of expertise, I have read a couple of articles that rely on the [PROSAIL](http://teledetection.ipgp.jussieu.fr/prosail/invleaf.pdf) model.
LAI is not a directly observable parameter, so it has to be modeled based. Depending on your area of interest, and forest composition, you may be able to do something simple, like a regression between a standard vegetation index (such as NDVI, EVI or SAVI) and in-situ LAI measurements, or you may have to go through a physical model like PROSAIL.